# How do I change the redirect page for unpublished nodes?

Tags: 7, redirection, nodes

It seems that the standard Drupal behaviour for unpublished nodes is this: If a visitor types in a URL to an unpublished node they are redirected to a login page. To -me- that signals that the content is 'there' but they just need credentials.

So: Is there a way to change this behaviour so that if they type in a URL to an unpublished node, literally -nothing- happens? Or perhaps they are redirected to the home page?

Below is my attempt to redirect to home page. The page still redirects to the Access Denied. What I don't get is that if I alter the Rule so that it tests for role 'Administrator' it works -fine-. So apparently an Anonymous user has some special property?

`{ "rules_redirect_unpubished_content_url_to_home_page" : {
    "LABEL" : "Redirect Unpubished Content URL To Home Page",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_view--bags_cases" : { "bundle" : "bags_cases" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT node_is_published" : { "node" : [ "node" ] } },
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "1" : "1" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "/" } } ]
  }
}`

I also tried this:

`function jch_utilities_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->status != 1) {
        drupal_goto('/some-page');
  }
}`

...and again, the 403 fires before this has a chance to run

Finally, I tried hook_init, but yet again, the 403 fires before this has a chance to run.

What am I missing?

Comment: The default behaviour is an "Access denied" page, because a visitor hasn't access to unpublished nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour is an "Access denied" page, because a visitor hasn't access to unpublished nodes.
It's not possible "nothing appens".
You could use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and create a Rule like this:

- event: viewing a node
- condition: user has role "anonymous"
- condtion: node is unpublished
- action: redirect to a custom page

Comment: My understanding is that an anonymous user doesn't have a Role. Can you explain what Condition I use to test for Anonymous users?

Comment: The role is a special role called "Anonymous". Go to `admin/people/permissions/roles` to see all the roles you have. Notice the 2 uneditable roles called Anonymous and Authenticated. Those are special roles used to identify logged in/anonymous users.

Comment: I understand that, but I can't get the rule to fire. Can you (someone) look at the Rule I posted above and tell me why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

this module will allow you to:

"setup redirects for each node type on their site. They can also set different types of redirects per node type. Developers can alter the node type list if required"

https://www.drupal.org/project/unpublished_nodes_redirect

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use this to get the node status:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  // Get the status 
  $status = $node->status ;
}
```

Your final module would then be something like this:

```
function your_module_init() {
  if (!function_exists('drush_main')) { // prevents issue with drush
    if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
      if ($node->status != 1) {
        drupal_goto('some-page'); // without the preceding /
      }
    }
  }
}
```